# How to SUMPRODUCT cells that contain formulas

Tags: excel, excel-formula

So, what I need is to show `SUMPRODUCT` of two cell ranges? Both of these cell ranges, that is, each cell contains formula in it. From this formulas I get some number in the cells. This is the way I'm doing it right now:

```
=SUMPRODUCT((S7:S1000)*(T7:T1000))
```

and because of formulas I get error `A value used in the formula if of the wrong data type`

How could I solve this problem? Is there some kind of way to read just number in the cell and not the formula?

Thanks

Comment: replacing "*" with comma as per chuff's reply will certainly ignore any text values (including "") returned by the formulas......but it may also ignore "numbers" formatted as text - what formulas do you have in S7:T1000?

Comment: What do you mean "number in the cell and not the formula", excel will evaluate formulas the do the `sumproduct` unless there is text as @barryhoudini states

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've had so much problems with this and in the end it was that instead of comma(",") I needed to use semicolon(";"). Maybe its up to Excel version, I'm using 2010?! So, solution was:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(S7:S1000;T7:T1000)
```

Comment: separators used are dictated by regional settings - if those are US or UK, for instance, then you need comma, if you have continental European settings then semi-colon

Comment: @Sylca You can and should mark your own answer as the solution, see http://stackoverflow.com/faq

Comment: Yes, but tomorrow :-)! You need two days to mark your answer as the solution!

Answer (score 4):

Replace the "*" with a comma (",").